# ¿Cómo hacer una consulta sin que se repitan los valores?

Tags: mysql, sql, subconsultas

Buen día amigos, supongamos tengo la siguiente tabla:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si yo hiciera la siguiente consulta "**SELECT * FROM Tabla WHERE IN Id_pedido (1, 2)**"
como resultado obtendría esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hasta ahí todo bien, mi pregunta es cómo hago para que sólo me muestre un registro por cada Id_pedido, es decir, en vez de mostrarme los dos que tienen el Id_pedido "2" me muestre algo así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Y cual es el criterio para seleccionar la fila del `Id-pedido=2`? pareciera ser el último de los `Nombre` en orden alfabético.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM Tabla WHERE IN Id_pedido (1, 2) GROUP BY Id_pedido
```

Esto sólo tomara el primer registro de los datos repetidos.

Answer (score 0):

Si, solamente incluyendo

```
GROUP BY Id_pedido
```